# PHP EXPORT MYSQL TO CSV - got column headers, can't get rest of data?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I can't seem to figure out why my table data won't appear in the csv file.
I have 1 page with a form submit to start the export process.
I am getting the correct column headers when I open the file with excel...

Thanks for the help!!

```
if(isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
        $host = "";
        $user = "";
        $password = "";
        $db = "";
        $con = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$password") or die("Couldn't connect to server.");  
        $db = mysql_select_db("$db", $con) or die ("Couldn't select database.");
        $table = "wp_users";

    function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'content.csv') {

    $csv_terminated = "\n";

    $csv_separator = ",";

    $csv_enclosed = '"';

    $csv_escaped = "\\";

    $query = "select * from $table";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $rowcount = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $data = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rowcount; $i++) {

    $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,

    mysql_field_name($result, $i)) . $csv_enclosed;

    $data .= $l;

    $data .= $csv_separator; }

    $output = trim(substr($data, 0, -1));

    $output .= $csv_terminated;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $data = '';

    for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++) {

    if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '') {

    if ($csv_enclosed == '') { $data .= $row[$j]; }

    else { $data .= $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed; } }

    else { $data .= ''; }

    if ($j < $rowcount - 1) { $data .= $csv_separator; } }

    $output .= $schema_insert;

    $output .= $csv_terminated; }

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($output));

    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");

    //header("Content-type: text/csv");

    //header("Content-type: application/csv");

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

    echo $output;

    exit;

    } 

    exportMysqlToCsv($table);

    }
```

Comment: waiting for the 'use mysqli...' comments in the next few minutes. XP

Comment: remove the header() and do a var_dump($output); to make sure you are getting the data...

Comment: @Wils - Thanks for the tip, I am indeed just getting the first row (ie - the column titles). Any insight on how to fix?

Comment: =) you should use a graphical or command line and make sure that you data in your table...When you are sure that you have data then you should review the code, comment some parts as you did for the header(), when you see the data then you start to put the pieces of code back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are assigning the CSV string to the `$data` variable but you are not appending it to `$output`. You need a line like:

```
$output .= $data;
```

just before:

```
$output .= $csv_terminated;
```

Secondly, I **really recommend** you to fix the code structure. It is very difficult to read the code the way it is right now. Read [PSR](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) standards for more information (or there are tons of decent standards).